# css not working in jsf

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I was created css file for prime-faces and i have tired to make it but not working .

this is my style.css file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org        /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
*{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;

}
 body{
background-color:#ffffff;
  }
 .head1{
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-image: url('images/rd-el_03.png');
height:174px;
 }
 .head2{
background-image: url('images/rd-el_02.png');
width:364px;
height:174px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
 img{
 border:0;
  }
 .footer1{
   background-image: url('images/rd-el_07.png');
  height:87px;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;   
  }
  .footer2{
  background-image: url('images/rd-el_06.png');
  float:left;
  width:89px;
  height:87px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

   }
 .footer3{
   background-image: url('images/rd-el_09.png');
  width:272px;
 height:87px;
 float:right;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;

  }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="head1">
 <div class="head2"></div>
</div>

 <div class="footer1">
 <a href="http://tl4s.com.sa" title="تصميم منتدى"><div class="footer2"></div></a>
 <div class="footer3"></div>
 </div>



  </body>

 </html>
```

this style.css is under
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- css
 |`-- style.css
 :

I have putted this code in my xhtml file but no luck

```
 <h:head>
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
 </h:head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it doesn't look like a CSS file. It is a HTML/XHTML file which has CSS code embedded in it. Remove all that HTML code and everything that is inside of  tags, put it in that CSS file! That will work.
So a CSS file looks like:

----------------------------------START----------------

```
.body{
 css code here
}

.property1{
 css code here
}
```

-------------------------------------------end------------------

There should be absolutely nothing else in it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem.

I resolved it by firstly using the `<h:outputStyleSheet>` tag
And I don't know if this will work for you because I'm using Maven, so you have to make sure your resource folder is inside:

```
webapp->resources->css->styles.css
```

and inside you `<h:head>` put the following line.
This is how JSF 2 references css files:

```
`<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  /> `
```

Hope this helps Goodluck